# How to obtain integral remainder in Taylor's formula for functions between Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

In Amann's textbook *Analysis II*, the authors present below version of Taylor's theorem.

---

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces.  Suppose $X$ is open in $E, q \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}$, and $f$ belongs to $C^{q}(X, F)$. We use the following notation:
$$
\partial^{k} f(x)[h]^{k}:=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
\partial^{k} f(x)[\underbrace{h, \ldots, h}_{k \text {-times }}], & 1 \leq k \leq q, \\
f(x), & k=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
for $x \in X, h \in E$, and $f \in C^{q}(X, F)$. YThen
$$
f(x+h)=\sum_{k=0}^{q} \frac{1}{k !} \partial^{k} f(x)[h]^{k}+R_{q}(f, x ; h)
$$
for $x \in X$ and $h \in E$ such that $[\![ x, x+h ]\!] \subset X$. Here
$$
R_{q}(f, x ; h):=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-t)^{q-1}}{(q-1) !}\left[\partial^{q} f(x+t h) \color{blue} {-\partial^{q} f(x)} \right][h]^{q} \mathrm d t \in F.
$$

---

I have come across a version (at page 64 of this [note](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5aeaabe5266c079fa248ceb0/t/6016d1f349c8cb642326587b/1612108276498/M3302-Lecturenotes.pdf)) with below integral remainder, i.e.,
$$
R_{q}(f, x ; h):=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-t)^{q-1}}{(q-1) !} \partial^{q} f(x+t h) [h]^{q} \mathrm d t.
$$

Is it possible to deduce this remainder from the version in my textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple integration by parts:
\begin{align}
R_{q,\text{book}}(f,x,h)&:=\int_0^1\frac{(1-t)^{q-1}}{(q-1)!}[\partial^qf(x+th)-\partial^qf(x)][h^q]\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1-\left(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{(1-t)^q}{q!}\right)[\partial^qf(x+th)-\partial^qf(x)][h^q]\,dt\\
&=\bigg[-\frac{(1-t)^q}{q!}[\partial^qf(x+th)-\partial^qf(x)][h^q]\bigg]_0^1\\
&-
\int_0^1\left(-\frac{(1-t)^q}{q!}\right)\frac{d}{dt}[\partial^qf(x+th)-\partial^qf(x)][h^q]\,dt\tag{IBP}\\\\
&= 0 +\int_0^1\frac{(1-t)^q}{q!}\partial^{q+1}f(x+th)[h^{q+1}]\,dt\\
&=R_{q,\text{notes}}(f,x,h).
\end{align}

Comment: Your IBP is valid if $\partial^{q+1} f$ exists and continuous. However, $f$ is only assumed to be $q$-times continuously differentiable.

Comment: @Analyst in the notes, it is assumed $f$ is $n+1$ times continuously differentiable, and I assume $n=q$, so $f$ is $q+1$ times continuously differentiable by hypothesis.

Comment: Ah I see. We can *not* obtain such an integral remainder that only involves $\partial^q f$ if $f$ is only $q$-times continuously differentiable??

Comment: @Analyst well, the book gives you such a formula (which is actually interesting because I had always thought having an integral form of the remainder requires one extra degree of smoothness), so I'm not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!