# Taylor's formula with integral remainder for complex value functions

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
be a smooth, real-valued function. Then it holds that

$$
f(x)- f(0) = x\cdot \nabla f(0)+ x\ \mbox{Hess}f(0)\ x^T + \sum_{|\alpha|=3,\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^m} \frac{x^\alpha}{\alpha!} \int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^2\ {\partial^\alpha} f(tx)\ dt.
$$

Now if we assume that $$f:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
is complex-valued, how to write the Taylor's formula? Is that same as  above?

I cannot find suitable reference (a book or paper) containing this kind formula explicitly. It is usually assumed that $f: \mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Where can I find such material?

(this [Page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384554/how-to-obtain-integral-remainder-in-taylors-formula-for-functions-between-banac) about the vector-valued version is helpful)

Comment: Do you mean $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb C$?

Comment: Oh, my bad.....

Comment: we can also start with $m=1$ :)

Comment: You might look for Taylor’s Theorem for mappings between Banach spaces.

Comment: Do you mean let $\mathbb{C}$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f(x) = f_1(x) + i f_2(x)= (f_1(x),f_2(x))$?

Comment: You can prove it yourself. Same exact proof as for real function. As @TedShifrin says, the same proof works even if codomain is a Banach space.

Comment: @Deane Thanks! I will try it.